# Is there such a thing as overall account quality score in Google AdWords?

Tags: google, keywords, google-ads, bidding

I see this referenced sometimes by adwords-consultants and it's used as an argument to buy ads for your own brand. However I have never seen any data to support this claim and Google doesn't seem to claim it either. Is there such a thing as overall account quality score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Google doesn't have enough information about a particular keyword, they estimate the quality score for it based on other factors including the quality score you have established for other keywords.   This ends up being a kind of quality score for your entire account.

Their [quality score help page](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2454010?hl=en) makes some reference to this pratice:

> To determine the auction-time quality components, we look at a number of different factors. By improving the following factors you can help improve the quality components of your Ad Rank:
>
> - ...
> - Geographic performance: How successful your account has been in the regions you're targeting
> - ...

[Here is a relevant article that discusses the existence or non-existance of an account quality score](http://searchengineland.com/account-level-quality-score-doesnt-exist-can-really-hurt-adwords-program-200651).  It says that Google has denied having such a metric in the past, but those denials may just be a matter of semantics.

I have personal experience with Google Adwords.   A few years ago I was managing a multi-million dollar AdWords account with millions of keywords in it.  It was actually a series of several accounts since each AdWords account has a keyword limit on it. Our AdWords representive at the time advised us to put our better performing keywords into a single account and use that account to get better prices on some other keywords for which Google was having to estimate the quality score.

A lot may have changed in the intervening years, but at the time, we took that as confirmation of some type of account level quality score.

Comment: Great answer! If I read you correctly, account quality will have most impact once new keywords are added but this will most likely be replaced once google get some real data?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the way it works.